# CheckBox "Cannot access 'checkBox01' before initialization"

Tags: javascript, html5

Não entendo, dei o ID da checkbox e chamei no javaScript como .value, mas quando marco e mando executar é dito Cannot access 'checkBox01' before initialization. 
Podem me ajudar? Obrigado.

```js
function metodoCalcular() {

 

 const notas = {

   primeiroBimestre: notaMatematica_1.value + " Nota referente ao 1º Bimestre de 2019",
   segundoBimestre: notaMatematica_2.value + " Nota referente ao 2º Bimestre de 2019",
   terceiroBimestre: notaMatematica_3.value + " Nota referente ao 3º Bimestre de 2019",    
   quartoBimestre: notaMatematica_4.value + " Nota referente ao 4º Bimestre de 2019",

 }



 let nota_01 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_1.value)
 let nota_02 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_2.value)
 let nota_03 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_3.value)
 let nota_04 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_4.value)

 let calcular = ((nota_01 +  nota_02 +  nota_03 + nota_04) / 4)

console.log(notas)

console.log("A média Final é de aluno é:", parseFloat(calcular.toFixed(2)))

let checkBox01 = checkBox01.value
let checkBox02 = checkBox02.value
let checkBox03 = checkBox03.value
let checkBox04 = checkBox04.value


if(checkBox01.checked){
console.log("A nota do primeiro Bimestre foi:", nota_01)
}
else if (checkBox02.checked){
console.log("A nota do segundo Bimestre foi: ", nota_02)
}
else if(checkBox03.checked){
console.log("A nota do terceiro Bimestre foi:", nota_03)
}
else if(checkBox04.checked){
console.log("A nota do quarto Bimestre foi:", nota_04)
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="metodoCalcular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/caelum/projeto01/fichaAcademiaComInterfaceGrafica/apostilaIgnore/libBrasil.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/caelum/projeto01/fichaAcademiaComInterfaceGrafica/apostilaIgnore/mostra.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <p>Nome:</p>
    <br>
    <input id="nome" type="text">
    <br>
    <p>Nota de Matemática 01:</p>
    <input id="notaMatematica_1" type="text">
    <br>
    <p>Nota de Matemática 02:</p>
    <input id="notaMatematica_2" type="text">
    <br>
    <p>Nota de Matemática 03:</p>
    <input id="notaMatematica_3" type="text">
    <br>
    <p>Nota de Matemática 04:</p>
    <input id="notaMatematica_4" type="text">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="checkBox01" type="checkbox">1º Bimestre</input>
    <input id="checkBox02" type="checkbox">2º Bimestre</input>
    <input id="checkBox03" type="checkbox">3º Bimestre</input>
    <input id="checkBox04" type="checkbox">4º Bimestre</input>
    <br>
    <br>

    <button onclick="metodoCalcular()">Cálcular</button>    
    <br>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você definiu os ID nos elementos HTML, mas em momento algum buscou os mesmos no DOM com o javascript.

Para buscar o elemento, existe diversas funções, como todo elemento tem um ID, e o ID deve ser único, o ideal é utilizar então da `getElementById`.

---

Então no começo da sua função, você poderia passar a buscar esses elementos:

```
const notaMatematica_1 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_1");
const notaMatematica_2 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_2");
const notaMatematica_3 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_3");
const notaMatematica_4 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_4");
```

Acima criamos as variáveis dos input/text, mas devemos fazer o mesmo com os checkbox:

```
const checkBox01 = document.getElementById("checkBox01");
const checkBox02 = document.getElementById("checkBox02");
const checkBox03 = document.getElementById("checkBox03");
const checkBox04 = document.getElementById("checkBox04");
```

Com isso, podemos apagar (apenas comentei como exemplo) a declaração das antigas variáveis:

```
//let checkBox01 = checkBox01.value
//let checkBox02 = checkBox02.value
//let checkBox03 = checkBox03.value
//let checkBox04 = checkBox04.value
```

Com isso seu código já passa a funcionar, veja abaixo o mesmo com as alterações efetuadas:

```js
function metodoCalcular() {

  const notaMatematica_1 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_1");
  const notaMatematica_2 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_2");
  const notaMatematica_3 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_3");
  const notaMatematica_4 = document.getElementById("notaMatematica_4");

  const checkBox01 = document.getElementById("checkBox01");
  const checkBox02 = document.getElementById("checkBox02");
  const checkBox03 = document.getElementById("checkBox03");
  const checkBox04 = document.getElementById("checkBox04");

  const notas = {
    primeiroBimestre: notaMatematica_1.value + " Nota referente ao 1º Bimestre de 2019",
    segundoBimestre: notaMatematica_2.value + " Nota referente ao 2º Bimestre de 2019",
    terceiroBimestre: notaMatematica_3.value + " Nota referente ao 3º Bimestre de 2019",    
    quartoBimestre: notaMatematica_4.value + " Nota referente ao 4º Bimestre de 2019",
  }

  let nota_01 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_1.value);
  let nota_02 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_2.value);
  let nota_03 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_3.value);
  let nota_04 = parseFloat(notaMatematica_4.value);

  let calcular = ((nota_01 +  nota_02 +  nota_03 + nota_04) / 4);

  if (Number.isNaN(calcular)) {
    calcular = 0;
  }

  console.log(notas)
  console.log("A média Final é de aluno é:", parseFloat(calcular.toFixed(2)));

  if(checkBox01.checked){
    console.log("A nota do primeiro Bimestre foi:", nota_01);
  }

  if (checkBox02.checked){
    console.log("A nota do segundo Bimestre foi: ", nota_02);
  }

  if(checkBox03.checked){
    console.log("A nota do terceiro Bimestre foi:", nota_03);
  }

  if(checkBox04.checked){
    console.log("A nota do quarto Bimestre foi:", nota_04);
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>

      <script src="metodoCalcular.js"></script>
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/caelum/projeto01/fichaAcademiaComInterfaceGrafica/apostilaIgnore/libBrasil.js"></script>
      <script src="https://rawgit.com/caelum/projeto01/fichaAcademiaComInterfaceGrafica/apostilaIgnore/mostra.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
      <p>Nome:</p>
      <br>
      <input id="nome" type="text">
      <br>
      <p>Nota de Matemática 01:</p>
      <input id="notaMatematica_1" type="text">
      <br>
      <p>Nota de Matemática 02:</p>
      <input id="notaMatematica_2" type="text">
      <br>
      <p>Nota de Matemática 03:</p>
      <input id="notaMatematica_3" type="text">
      <br>
      <p>Nota de Matemática 04:</p>
      <input id="notaMatematica_4" type="text">

      <br>
      <br>

      <input id="checkBox01" type="checkbox">1º Bimestre
      <input id="checkBox02" type="checkbox">2º Bimestre
      <input id="checkBox03" type="checkbox">3º Bimestre
      <input id="checkBox04" type="checkbox">4º Bimestre

      <br>
      <br>

      <button onclick="metodoCalcular()">Cálcular</button>    
      <br>

  </body>

</html>
```

Note que tem algumas outras coisas, o valor dos input/text não estão sendo tratados, logo eles podem estar vazios e gerar erro de NaN durate os cálculos, tratei apenas no resultado como exemplo com a `IsNaN`, mas o correto seria tratar todos os valores. Também removi os `else if` da verificação de `checked`, caso contrário, somente a primeira seleção seria exibida no console, mesmo marcando as demais.

---

> Referência:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: Obrigado Daniel ! Deu super certo ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Você não criou uma referência nas variáveis para os `checkbox`. Seu código na seguinte linha está errado no qual vai te retornar um erro:

```
let checkBox01 = checkBox01.value
let checkBox02 = checkBox02.value
let checkBox03 = checkBox03.value
let checkBox04 = checkBox04.value
```

Use, por exemplo, o método `querySelector` para poder para apontar os `checkbox` no HTML:

```
let checkBox01 = document.querySelector("#checkBox01").value;
let checkBox02 = document.querySelector("#checkBox02").value;
let checkBox03 = document.querySelector("#checkBox03").value;
let checkBox04 = document.querySelector("#checkBox04").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando  a resposta do Leandro, você pode utilizar o getElementById.value também.

```
let checkBox01 = document.getElementById("#checkBox01").value;
let checkBox02 = document.getElementById("#checkBox02").value;
let checkBox03 = document.getElementById("#checkBox03").value;
let checkBox04 = document.getElementById("#checkBox04").value;
```